# How can I dynamically access user control attributes?

Tags: asp.net, collections, icollection, dynamic-usercontrols

Im trying to create a "user control menu" where links to a page's usercontrols are placed at the top of the page.  This will allow me to put several usercontrols on a page and allow the user to jump to that section of the page without scrolling so much.  In order to do this, I put each usercontrol in a folder (usercontrols) and gave each control a Description property (`<%@ Control Language="C#" Description = "Vehicles" .... %>`).

My question is how can I access this description dynamically?  I want to use this description as the link in my menu.  So far, I have a foreach on my page that looks in the ControlCollection for a control that is of the ASP.usercontrols type.  If it is I would assume that I could access its attributes and grab that description property.  How can I do this?  (Im also open to a better way to achieve my "user control menu", but maybe thats another question.)  Should I use `((System.Web.UI.UserControl)mydynamiccontrol).Attributes.Keys`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can iterate over the collection and do either a switch or a few if statements

I would suggst you have an interface or an abstract base class for all your user controls:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass : UserControl
{
  public abstract string MyDescription {get;}
}

public MyUserControlA : MyBaseClass
{
  public string MyDescription {get {return "my description";}}
}

public MyUserControlB : MyBaseClass
{
  public string MyDescription {get {return "my other description";}}
}
```

Then you can loop over them as you do:

```
foreach ...
if (mydynamiccontrol is MyBaseClass)
{
    Response.Write(((MyBaseClass)mydynamiccontrol).MyDescription);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I think you make a good point.  Im probably making this harder than I should.  Im still curious how to access the Description attribute in the user control.  If I try to iterate over the attribute collection, I just get an empty collection.